# Rate of change of frequency

Tags: derivatives

I came across an expression that physically means rate of change of frequency. Is there any physical interpretation to this derivative of frequency? Thanks.

Comment: the physical interpretation is rate of change of frequency!

Comment: I get that. I mean "inertia response power" or something like that I see. But not sure if there is some common physical quantity associated with it - like velocity which is the rate of change of position.

Comment: I suggest you to change the question to ‘is there a physical term/quantity for rate of change of frequency?’, and post it on Physics SE.

Comment: Sure. Will do - thanks!